# Toolbar height Out of Range - MvvmCross

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I try the XPlatformMenus from the github

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/tree/master/XPlatformMenus

It runs well and trying to run some test by adding the icon on the Side Menu

Here is what happen after the login

[image]

Here is the navigation_drawer.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <group android:id="@+id/nav_items">
      <item
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:title="Home" />        
    </group>
    <item android:title="Examples">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_viewpager"
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_event"
                android:title="ViewPager" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_recyclerview"
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_headset"
                android:title="Recyclerview" />
        </menu>
    </item>
    <group android:id="@+id/nav_footer">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
            android:title="Settings" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_helpfeedback"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
            android:title="Help and Feedback" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

Comment: Update: Just download from repo again , seems like there is a bug in the init on the View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be fixed by changing the `layout_height` of the toolbar layout to `wrap_content`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```